# Android: How to change src of the imageButton in OnClickListener?

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have the following image button:

```
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/data_btn_favourite"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_grade_gray"
        style="@style/AppTheme.ListViewItem.FavouriteIcon"/>
```

Which onClickListener is initialized this way:

```
holder.favourite.setOnClickListener(mFavouriteBtnListener);


private View.OnClickListener mFavouriteBtnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Logger.d("Favourite button clicked");
            MyData myDatObj = ((MyData) view.getTag());
            mDataController.markItemAsFavourite(myDatObj, view, holder.favourite);
        }
    };
```

holder.favourite is ImageButton

And in called method

```
public void markItemAsFavourite(MyData myData, View view, ImageButton imageButton) {
```

Trying to set new image resource using the

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_blue);
```

But without any success. I would like to ask, how to do it in the right way?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml file in your drawable as imagebtn.xml and paste this code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_focused"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_while_notpressed" />  
</selector>
```

and try this in your activity

```
button_information.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagebtn);
```

The background image changes upon focused and pressed.

Comment: I think, that your solution is not suitable for me, because src is changed after the HTTP request result.

Answer (score 0):

Use holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_blue); instead of imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_info_blue);

Comment: Same result, image is not changed.

Comment: Could you please post your complete adapter code. I will be able to help you in a better way then.